# How to add the "about" button in permissions for an Android app?

Tags: android, android-permissions

I recently downloaded the Fitbit app and wanted to give it all permissions. I noticed that each permission has an "About" button that redirects users to a website about the permission. I've added an activity that shows the permissions from my app, and I'd like to add this same "About" button feature. How can I do this?[image]

I want to add this feature into my app, how can I do it?

The “Permissions” page of my app currently has this layout, particularly in the “About” section. The PermissionsActivity is a separate activity that I intend to connect with the “About” buttons.

[image]

Comment: If you've already done the Activity, it's just buttons with click listener and then start a Web browser intent. What are your exact problems with it?

Comment: I made the `PermissionsActivity.kt` but I am truggling with adding the 'About' buttons to each permission found in the Android Settings app under my app name -> Permissions. These buttons provide additional information about each permission when clicked. My question is, how can I implement these “About” buttons, to be shown in my app and ensure they link correctly to my PermissionsActivity.kt?

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/explaining-access#privacy-dashboard-show-rationale. It's not too popular approach I guest

Comment: I didn't find any useful information there. :/

Comment: It's the `activity` with `intent-filter` to listen for users (!) button clicked. Check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the Privacy dashboard:

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/explaining-access#privacy-dashboard

> Decide what your data access rationale activity should show. For
> example, you might show your app's website or a help center article.
> To provide a more detailed explanation about the types of data that
> your app accesses, as well as when the access occurred, handle the
> extras that the system includes when it invokes the permission usage
> intent:

Define your `PermissionsActivity` with `intent-filter` as stated in the document to show when users tap on the (!) button on the App's permissions page or from the Permission usage page:

```
<activity android:name=".PermissionsActivity"
          android:permission="android.permission.START_VIEW_PERMISSION_USAGE"
          android:exported="true">
       <!-- VIEW_PERMISSION_USAGE shows a selectable information icon on
            your app permission's page in system settings.
            VIEW_PERMISSION_USAGE_FOR_PERIOD shows a selectable information
            icon on the Privacy Dashboard screen. -->
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW_PERMISSION_USAGE" />
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW_PERMISSION_USAGE_FOR_PERIOD" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       ...
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Useful post here: https://yggr.medium.com/exploring-android-12-data-access-rationale-f0e713e87f96

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed response. Sorry I was a bit angry when I read the article, and I didn't pay enough attention at the moment. <3